# GAE Calling Servlet with user authenticated through gapi.auth.authorize

Tags: google-app-engine, google-oauth, google-cloud-endpoints

I have a Google Cloud Endpoint which I access from an HTML page through JavaScript and the Google JavaScript client Library.

I authenticate with OAuth2.0 by using the standard

```
gapi.auth.authorize({client_id: CLIENT_ID, scope: SCOPES, immediate: mode}, callback);
```

Everything works correctly and I am able to read/write data from/to the underlying Datastore.

In the same AppEngine project I have a servlet that generates a PDF based on data that is in the Datastore.

I would like to be able to call this Servlet from my HTML page using the same user that was authenticated through the api.auth.authorize() method.

And in the servlet, get the User through

```
UserService userService = UserServiceFactory.getUserService();
```

and query the datastore for the data of this user and then generate a PDF showing this data.

I have no idea how to call this url (servlet) with the credentials of the OAuth autheticated user.

Can you help me please??
Thanks in advance!

Note that the same question was asked some months ago but without a "complete" answer: [GAE User API with OAuth2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25211395/gae-user-api-with-oauth2)

Comment: I haven't found any answer to my question so far but I would like to share a solution to the business requirement which underlies my question. So in a nutshell the requirement is to produce a PDF base on some data in the Datastore and linked to a specific user which is authenticated through OAuth via the Google JavaScript client Library. My solution is based on Cloud Storage. I first create a bucket in Cloud Storage for each user and secure the bucket to allow access only to this user. I generate the PDF in a Endpoint and write it to a ByteArrayOutputStream (named 'os'). See next comment.

Comment: I then save it to Cloud Storage via `GcsFileOptions options = new GcsFileOptions.Builder().mimeType("application/pdf").build();
GcsOutputChannel outputChannel = gcsService.createOrReplace(gcsfileName, options);
ByteBuffer buf = ByteBuffer.wrap(os.toByteArray());
outputChannel.write(buf);
outputChannel.close();`
The user can then open the PDF through the following url `https://storage.cloud.google.com/-bucketname-/-filename-` if an and only if he has authenticated before with his Google account (in particular from the page that called the Endpoint). I hope this will help someone!

Answer (score 0):

You should look into [bucket/object ACLs](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/access-control). When your API endpoint gets the User object, it can use [the user's email](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/users/userclass#User_email) to set the ACL on the PDF which is generated. That way, you can serve the PDF file to the user simply using its URL. You could also check with an endpoints API call whether the user is indeed authenticated as the person who is allowed to access the requested PDF (having stored a Datastore entry, perhaps, parallel to the object), and generate a [signed URL](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/access-control#Signed-URLs) once this is confirmed.